# Одобрение/отклонение правок от нескольких пользователей в тексте?

Tags: php, алгоритм, веб-программирование, архитектура

Добрый вечер, друзья. В целом адекватно сформулировать вопрос, полностью отражающий суть проблемы крайне сложно, потому постараюсь пояснить, что я имею ввиду.

Если кратко, то мне необходимо доработать [Text_Diff](https://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff) (я абсолютно не привязан конкретно к данной библиотеке, просто это первое, что я нашел в сети) так, чтобы помимо сравнения двух версий имелась возможность - отображать + удалять/восстанавливать правки по пользователям + на основе этого формировать конечный документ из:

"Исходная версия текста" -> "Одобренные правки" -> "Конечная версия текста".

Например:

> ***Исходная версия***
>
> Это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.

---

> ***Одобренная правка Пользователя 1***
>
> Это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. **Дополнение от пользователя 1**

---

> ***Одобренная правка Пользователя 2***
>
> Это **не только** текст-"рыба" **но и текст ракообразный**, часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. **Дополнение от пользователя 2**

---

> ***Отклоненная правка Пользователя 3***
>
> Это **фееричный бред** текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. **Хрень от пользователя 3**

---

> ***Модераторская версия***
>
> Это *фееричный бред* **не только** текст-"рыба" **но и текст ракообразный**, часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. **Дополнение от пользователя 1****Дополнение от пользователя 2***Хрень от пользователя 3*

---

> ***Итоговая версия***
>
> Это **не только** текст-"рыба" **но и текст ракообразный**, часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. **Дополнение от пользователя 1****Дополнение от пользователя 2**

*Важно заметить что все правки добавляются не друг за другом, а относительно исходной версии текста*

Проблемы у меня возникают с построение архитектуры как таковой, так как ничего более здравого, чем десятки сравнений версий текста на каждого пользователя, я не придумал.

Пока мой неюзабельный набросок выглядит так:

1. Создаем таблицу, где храним текст каждой правки пользователя *(текст правки каждого пользователя вычленяем, сравнивая исходную версию текста и версию пользователя с правками, разницу записываем в таблицу)*
2. Создаем таблицу с общим текстом правок от всех пользователей для последующего сравнения с текстом от каждого пользователя и подсвечиванием их правок *(вот тут тупик, так как мне совсем не ясно как работать с очередностью текста, ведь каждая новая правка будет вноситься относительно исходной версии документа, а не друг за другом)*
3. В случае, если два отдельных пользователя затрагивают один и тот же текст, в документе размещаем их друг за другом *(тоже пробел, гипотетически можно провести перекрёстное сравнение с предыдущей общей версией с внесенными правками от прочих пользователей, версией с правками от текущего пользователя и исходной версией для выделение повторяющихся правок, но звучит так себе)*

По итогу вызовов text_diff, там будет невероятно много *(и даже с сравнением всего и вся проблема хронологии сохраняется)*, что убого как по архитектуре, так и по производительности. Потому хотел бы попросить у вас помощи с поиском верного направления мысли или, еще лучше, со ссылкой на готовую библиотеку xD.

Спасибо всем, кто дочитал до конца...

**P.s** и да, я знаю, что мне не мешало бы прочесть курс по алгоритмам, изучить виды сортировок, etc. И в будущем я обязательно этим займусь. И да, я так же знаю, что по хорошему я всё это должен знать, но уж извините...

Answer (score 0):

> Просто текст который был изначально!
>   Не просто текст который был изначально!
>   Просто ужасный текст который был изначально!
>   Просто текст который был не изначально!

Сравниваем строки по словам, не исходные с исходным без учёта регистра, 
например, начиная с первого:

```
1) Не -> Просто
1.1) Не совпало, записали в массив слово "Не" $arr[1] - ключ 1 т.к слово первое
2) просто -> Просто
...
```

второй:

```
1) Просто -> Просто
2) ужасный -> текст 
2.1) Не совпало, записали в массив слово "Не" $arr[2] - ключ 2 т.к слово второе
...
```

третий:

```
1) Просто -> Просто
2) текст -> текст
3) который -> который
4) был -> был
5) не -> изначально 
5.1) Не совпало, записали в массив слово "не" $ar[5] - ключ 5 т.к слово пятое
...
```

Теперь объединяем, берем $arr[m] и дописываем в начальную строку "слова" зная номера "слов" в [m].

Для нашего случая это выглядит так:

Сортируем массив по [m]

$arr[1] - Подставим [1] слово номер один

> Не

$arr[2] - Подставим [2] слово номер один из главного сообщения, потом наше слово под номером два, которое изменилось

> Не Просто ужасный

$arr[5] - слова, под номерами 2,3,4 из главного сообщения, потом наше слово под номером пять, и т.к. больше ничего нет добиваем остальные слова из сообщения по умолчанию.

> Не Просто ужасный текст который был не изначально!

Также, если ключи [m] совпали, объединяйте значения с помощью пробела.

Если слова при сравнении не совпали, вы слово из изменённого сообщения берите новое, и сравнивайте опять с исходным тем-же словом (которое было в предыдущем сравнении), и если опять не совпало, объединяйте с тем-же ключом!

**Постскриптум:** про удаление слов что-то аналогичное можно додумать и, конечно добавить к этому описанию функционал с Учётом регистра!